# How can I copy a path in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'd like to recreate a whole chain of nodes and relationships in Neo4j.

I know that I can save a path with `p=`, but `CREATE` doesn't accept this.

```
MATCH p=(:Person)-[*]->(:Dog) CREATE p
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you could try working with `nodes(p)` and `relationships(p)`

Comment: Can you explain why you want to create exact duplicates of a set of paths within the same DB? This is usually something you want to  avoid. If we knew what you are actually trying to accomplish, maybe we can suggest a better way.

Comment: @cybersam too true, one would generally want to avoid this. It's alright in my case, I'm populating sample data so it's fine for there to be duplicates. There are other ways to populate sample data, but this is a theoretical question. I was a bit surprised that the command I tried didn't work. An "it's not possible" answer is totally acceptable, or if there's a way of doing it, it would be interesting to know. In either way, the answer should probably be accompanied by a "WARNING: you probably don't want to do this", as you've mentioned.

Comment: @cybersam I have a use case for this where I would like to repeatedly use a set of nodes as a 'template' (and have multiple templates) that is duplicated and attached elsewhere.  Right now I'm programmatically creating them using py2neo and reading CREATE commands from cypher script files, but it would be nice to operate entirely on the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WARNING: One would usually create additional relationships to nodes rather than duplicate nodes in a graph database.

This is not *strictly* Cypher, but works in [the Neo4j shell](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/shell-starting.html). It should work as of Neo4j 2.0.0. A word of caution: this is listed as an experimental and incomplete feature.

```
dump MATCH (pers:Person)-[r*:OWNS]->(d:Dog) RETURN pers,r,d;
```

You can directly execute the returned output to duplicate the nodes. IDs will be changed if they already exist. The nodes and relationships will be created with the same labels and properties.

This is super handy for backing up a database.

[More info on the dump command](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/shell-commands.html#_dumping_the_database_or_cypher_statement_results)

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen, the syntax you tried does not work, so one would have to attempt to write *a lot of Cypher code* to copy all the parts of each path.

**However, it turns out that it is not currently possible to use Cypher alone to duplicate arbitrary paths -- as some needed capabilities are missing.**

For example, although you can use the `LABELS()` function to get a collection containing an existing node's labels, there is no way to create/set another node's label from that data. Cypher only supports *hardcoded* labels (when creating a node, as in `CREATE (n:Foo)`; and when updating a node, as in `SET n:Foo`). A similar consideration applies to relationship types.

Comment: Currently verifying if there's not a _fairly_ simple way that was missed to accomplish this. If I find one, I'll post it. If not, I'll accept your answer.