# Cypher Access Nodes of Variable Length Path

Tags: neo4j, cypher, variable-length

I have the following problem:

I have a `MATCH` clause like this one:

`MACTH (A)-[*1..]->(B)`

Now, if this pattern matches, I need to somehow duplicate the `-[*1..]->` part and replace all node in it tat have a specific type with nodes of another type.

for example if I had this graph:

`(X1:A)-[:r]->(X2:B)-[:r]->(X3:E)-[:r]->(X4:A)`

I might want to get this graph after applying a rule `MACTH (A:A)-[*1..]->(B:A) something something`

`(X1:A)-[:r]->(X2:B)-[:r]->(X3:E)-[:r]->(X4:A) , (X1)-[:r]->(X5:C)-[:r]->(X3)-[:r]->(X4)`

by duplicating the path between `(A)` and `(B)` and replacing all nodes of type `B` with type `C`

But how can I access the `-[*1..]->` part of the query?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Match (p:Person)-[:RELATED*1..]->(e) 
with collect(distinct(id(e))) as ids Match (c:Country) where id(c) in ids 
remove c:Country set c:NewLabel 
return *
```

on data

```
Create (p:Person)-[:RELATED]->(b:Person)-[:RELATED]->(c:Client)-[:RELATED]->(e:Country) return *
```

Comment: This changes the label of `c`. How do I however copy that new path so I end up with both versions of c (`c:Country` and `c:NewLabel`) ?

Comment: I didn't manage to understand what do you want to get at your database at the end? Should there be two different nodes one with label Country another with label NewLabel?

Comment: yes exactly. I want to duplicate the path and in the duplicate path change nodes with label 1 into nodes with label 2.

Comment: As far as I uderstood  there is another problem to copy all the path. To deal with it there is experemental fiture http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/shell-commands.html#_dumping_the_database_or_cypher_statement_results
 And also you could look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586224/how-can-i-copy-a-path-in-neo4j
Maybe there is another way, but my knowlage is not enoght to answer ti